# Synchronize nodes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I've got following situation:

Two sensors nodes are publishing different values on different topics at 1khz:

SensorNode A publishes measured contact force values

SensorNode B publishes measured angles

Further I've got two subscribers for these two publishers:

Subscriber subA

Subscriber subB

Both Subscriber write on the same state-Object (state.force and state.angle)

Method void control(state.force,state.angle) is called in the CallBackRoutine of subB and does some calculations based on the measured force and measured angle. But what happens is that the force-values and angle-values don't match.

Sometimes it like in the Callback-Routine of subA values are written on state.force 5 times without having been read or sometimes in the Callback-Routine of subB state.force is read 5 times though they values couldn't be updated by subA

How can I synchronize the two nodes? I'm coding in C++ but I'm really new to ROS.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71848/synchronize-nodes/) by [invoices](https://answers.ros.org/users/5638/invoices/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-08-08**:
Is there any reason you're not using a single node with two subscribers instead of two different nodes?

**Comment by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on 2013-08-08**:
Maybe you can use a time-stamp to make sure your data sensor match well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are lots of possible solutions but the [message_filter](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) packages has a good solution either in one of the TimeSynchronizer filters.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0